# Why does it look like a closure borrows self instead of a field of self?

Tags: rust, self, borrow-checker, borrowing

Why does the following code fail in the borrow checker?

```
struct X(pub i32);
impl X {
    fn run<F>(&mut self, f: F) -> i32
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> i32,
    {
        f() * self.0
    }
}

struct Y {
    a: i32,
    b: X,
}
impl Y {
    fn testme(&mut self) -> i32 {
        let x = || self.a;
        self.b.run(x)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut x = Y { a: 100, b: X(100) };
    println!("Result: {}", x.testme());
}
```

With the error ([Playground](http://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=39b15f1a078bb32c885c1804e6750c09&version=stable&mode=debug))

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.b` as mutable because `self` is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:18:9
   |
17 |         let x = || self.a;
   |                 -- ---- previous borrow occurs due to use of `self` in closure
   |                 |
   |                 immutable borrow occurs here
18 |         self.b.run(x)
   |         ^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
19 |     }
   |     - immutable borrow ends here
```

It looks like the closure `x` borrowed `self` in `testme()`; shouldn't it have only borrowed `self.a`? Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [Mutably borrow one struct field while borrowing another in a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36379242/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: TL;DR the duplicate: yes, the entire `self` is borrowed by the closure. You need to split out the borrow of the field before the closure.