# Is there an elegant way to rewrite getting or creating an Option using a `match` statement?

Tags: rust, pattern-matching, option-type

I boiled my code down to these lines:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Config {
    values: Vec<String>,
    compiled: Option<Vec<String>>,
}

impl Config {
    fn comp_values(&mut self) -> &Vec<String> {
        if self.compiled.is_none() {
            self.compiled = Some(self.values.clone());
        }
        self.compiled.as_ref().unwrap()
    }

    fn comp_values_match(&mut self) -> &Vec<String> {
        match self.compiled {
            Some(_) => self.compiled.as_ref().unwrap(),
            None => {
                self.compiled = Some(self.values.clone());
                self.compiled.as_ref().unwrap()
            }
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut c = Config {
        values: vec![String::from("a"), String::from("b")],
        compiled: None,
    };
    println!("config before: {:?}", c);
    println!("compiled: {:?}", c.comp_values());
    println!("config after: {:?}", c);
}
```

What I would like to have is something like:

```
match self.compiled {
    Some(v) => v,
    None => {
        // assemble v and assign it to self.compiled
        v
    },
}
```

just like in the [closure chapter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch13-01-closures.html#storing-closures-using-generic-parameters-and-the-fn-traits) in the book. Is it possible in the book it only worked, because `u32` implements the `Copy` trait? If I change the `match` line to `match self.compiled.as_ref()` the `Some(v) => v,` works. In the `None` arm I then can't assign like `self.compiled = ...` since I have have the variable 'open' (or referenced with `self.compiled.as_ref()`) in that block.

Are my assumptions correct? Is the `comp_values()` method the most elegant solution in that case?

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=996a256c8a627e24079c634dbf20c94a)

Comment: [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks for the hint with &[...]
With your code: the `Self {...} = self` you are basically deconstructing the struct and create new local variables which are references, right? But why isn't `self.compiled.get_or_insert_with(|| self.values.clone())` not working? Is it because with your solution I get multiple `&mut` idependent from each other and with my solution one reference within anoghter? Sorry my bad english...

Comment: That's absolutely correct. The closure captures `self` and the compiler effectively doesn't know what you will do with it at that point, so it can't guarantee that it's safe. Borrowing the fields beforehand make it very clear that they don't overlap. See also [Mutably borrow one struct field while borrowing another in a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36379242/155423) (Your English is fine!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a `match` statement, but I think you are looking for [`get_or_insert_with`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert_with).

Comment: Please look for duplicate questions and vote to close instead of answering them.